# Reshaping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe shape:

```
                      date,        close
exchange, symbol      
CME       ES          2015-02-25   123
          YM          2015-02-25   345
          NQ          2015-02-25   456
          ES          2015-02-26   875
          YM          2015-02-26   742
          NQ          2015-02-26   235
```

Currently it uses a multi-index (ie: exchange + symbol). I need to change the shape of this dataframe so that the index is the date and the column is 'close' which is listed underneath exchange + symbol. The result should basically be something like this:

```
                              close
(exchange, symbol)            (CME, ES)    (CME, YM)    (CME NQ)
date
2015-02-25                    123          345           456
2015-02-26                    875          742           235
```

I have tried pivot/unstack/stack which im sure is the correct way to accomplish this, however I have been unable to get the desired shape.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Basically I set up a similar dataframe to yours.... my dataframe is here:

```
 symbol        date  close
     ES  25/02/2015    123
     YM  25/02/2015    456
     NQ  25/02/2015    789
     ES  26/02/2015    123
     YM  26/03/2015    456
     NQ  26/03/2015    789


df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path, index_col = None)

print df.pivot(index = 'date', columns = 'symbol', values = 'close')
```

output:

```
symbol       ES   NQ   YM
date                     
25/02/2015  123  789  456
26/02/2015  123  789  456
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score -1):

for getting the 'date' column as an index you can do something like:

```
 df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
```

after this the other columns will automatically organize themselves.

Comment: to remake the dataframe... you just state the order you want e.g:
df = df[['date', 'columnA', 'columnB' ..... etc]]

Comment: Im not sure I see how this will work because I need the columns to be multi-level, ie: for each exchange/symbol there is a close. So the index will be date, but the columns need to be multi-level. Perhaps you can elaborate in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: im still having no luck with this. I am fairly certain pivot/stack/unstack needs to be used but I just can't get it working to create the correct dataframe shape as per the original question (with each exchange+symbol having a list of 'close' values underneath)